# Visual Studio 2015 does not show the tree structure of an exe file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, exe

I'm trying to open the setup.exe file created by **Visual Studio Installer** in order to change its icon.

It seems that Visual Studio 2013 shows a tree when you open an exe file,
example:
[image]

Visual Studio 2015 shows the binary content of the exe file instead:
[image]

How to see the exe tree structure using Visual Studio 2015?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean "tree", not "three". And you want the Resource Editor.

<kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Open</kbd> > <kbd>File...</kbd> > (select the file, but do not click open) > <kbd>Open with...</kbd> (it's in the Open split-button menu) > <kbd>Resource Editor</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thank you, in the "Open With" window, I don't have "Resource Editor" listed. Do you know how to add it? should I install a Visual Studio plugin to have it listed?

Comment: @Alessandro Which edition of VS2015 do you have installed?

Comment: @Alessandro you may need to install more C++ components from VS setup.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. What did the trick for me I suppose was to re-run the Visual Studio installer and install the Visual Studio Extensibility Tools.